# Converting from spherical coordinates to cartesian around arbitrary vector N

Tags: math, vector, coordinates, trigonometry, algebra

So if I'm given an arbitrary unit vector N and another vector V defined in spherical coordinates theta (polar angle between N and V) and phi (azimuthal angle) and r = 1. How do I convert vector V into cartesian coordinates?

Now, I know that in general the conversion from spherical to cartesian is as follows:

```
x = r * sin theta * cos phi 
y = r * sin theta * sin phi 
z = r * cos theta
```

However, since the angles theta and phi are defined respective to the vector N and not the axes, the above conversion wouldn't work, yes? So how would I go about modifying the conversion?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Comment: There is an available mathematics tab, so it appears that there is room on this site for math questions.

Comment: Yes, but the intersection with some programming topic has to be non-empty.

Comment: This is meant for an algorithm I am implementing for a graphics program.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that this is simply not possible given the information you have to hand.

You cannot have a vector `V` with spherical polar components defined relative to another *vector*. In a standard spherical polar coordinate system, the coordinates of a point `P` are given by `(r,theta,phi)` where `theta` is the polar angle, `phi` azimuthal angle, and `r` the Euclidean distance from the origin. The polar angle is the angle between the z-axis and the line joining the origin to the point `P`. The azimuthal angle is defined as the angle between the x-axis and the line that joins the origin to the orthogonal projection of `P` onto the `xy` plane.

Sometimes the definitions of these two angles are reversed. The above is clearly illustrated at the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polars

The point here is that the angles are defined relative to **two** mutually orthogonal axes - z and x in this case. Thus you cannot have **both** of your polar and azimuthal angles defined relative to a single vector `N` - You can have ONE of them measured relative to `N` but not both.

As it stands, your problem cannot be solved without providing another vector orthogonal to your `N` that provides the axis to which the other angle (either polar or azimuthal) is measured.

Your description of `N` indicates that this is the z-axis of some rotated coordinate system that `V` takes its polar angle relative to. You need another vector that gives the x-axis of the same rotated coordinate system that `V` takes measures its azimuthal angle relative to. With that information you can obtain the rotation matrix that maps your rotated coordinate system axes onto the cartesian coordinate axes - from there you will have sufficient information to obtain the cartesian coordinates of `V` that you require.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this one: http://www.ewerksinc.com/refdocs/coordinate%20and%20unit%20vector.pdf

On page 7 you'll find the conversion formulas between spherical and cartesian vectors.

Comment: Could you also extract the relevant content from the link, just in case it gets removed/modified?

Comment: And the link is gone.